# node.js base class for abstracting get/put logic to storage

Tags: node.js, architecture, model, middleware

I was wondering if anyone had any good examples of a node.js base "class" for abstracting out the get/put logic to storage.  For example pseudo code.  I realize it would prototypcal inheritance, i am just looking for a clean way to do this so i can split of the files for each of the pieces of functionality.  Or what would be the best way to roll our own ORM, but very dumbed down, just models and this base class?  Are models worth it?

```
class base

  function get(id, cb) {
    cb(null, obj);
  }

  function put(id, obj, cb) {
    cb(null, obj);
  }
```

Then i could have "child" classes

```
class function1
  function getFunction1(id, cb) {
    // do some other stuff.
    super.get(id, cb);
  }
```

so then as usage it makes it clean.

```
var function1 = require('./function1');
function1.getFunction1('id' function(err, result) {});
function1.putFunction1('');
```

Would it be worth or do you have an example of making this "functions" be all defined in single place, almost like middleware/plugins?